# Round and groupby hour values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable like this in pandas that list specific time

```
Time
19:05
20:18
20:44
20:51
06:11
06:23
08:37
11:59
```

What I'd like to have is a column with the adjusted rounded time (eg 11:59 -> 12:00 or 19:05 -> 19:00) and another column where the hours between 22:00 till 06:00 are considered "night" and the hours between 07:00 and 21:00 are considered "day"

```
Time    Time_rnd     DN
19:05     19:00      Day
20:18     20:00      Day
20:44     21:00      Day
20:51     21:00      Day
23:34     23:00      Night
03:11     03:00      Night
04:23     04:00      Night
08:37     09:00      Day
11:59     12:00      Day
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Thank you

Comment: What would be your logic of doing this, if you were to do this manually? Try writing that in simple python and please share your code.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import pandas as pd

df_time = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        '19:05',
        '20:18',
        '20:44',
        '20:51',
        '06:11',
        '06:23',
        '08:37',
        '11:59',
    ],
    columns=['time']
)

# Convert the hour-strings into date-time. Set as index.
df_time.index = pd.to_datetime(df_time['time']).dt.round('H')

# Create new column--default value "Night"
df_time['time of day'] = 'Night'

# Filter for items between specified times--set to "Day"
df_time.loc[df_time.between_time('07:00', '21:00').index, 'time of day'] = 'Day'
```

```
                    time    time of day
time        
2021-07-10 19:00:00 19:05   Day
2021-07-10 20:00:00 20:18   Day
2021-07-10 21:00:00 20:44   Day
2021-07-10 21:00:00 20:51   Day
2021-07-10 06:00:00 06:11   Night
2021-07-10 06:00:00 06:23   Night
2021-07-10 09:00:00 08:37   Day
2021-07-10 12:00:00 11:59   Day
```

It's a different approach than specifically what you've outlined, but using [`ts.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) appears more elegant, IMO.

---

Edit:
OP Asked about removing the dates from the dataframe, since they weren't in the original prompt. It appears they would best be removed from the index as well.

Adding the following to the bottom of the script above will accomplish this:

```py
# change the index to a formatted string, to remove the date
df_time.index = pd.Index(df_time.index.strftime('%H:%M'), name='rounded time')

# reset the index to remove the stringified datetime out of the index
df_time = df_time.reset_index()
```

```
    rounded time    time    time of day
0   19:00           19:05   Day
1   20:00           20:18   Day
2   21:00           20:44   Day
3   21:00           20:51   Day
4   06:00           06:11   Night
5   06:00           06:23   Night
6   09:00           08:37   Day
7   12:00           11:59   Day
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I only have two issue:
1. is there a way to have in the column only the hour in this format HH:MM withuot the today date?
2. and also when trying to use the secondo part of the code I'm gettin this error 
```TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex ```
I'm using it like this:
```
df['time of day'] = 'Night'
df['time_rnd'].loc[['time_rnd'].between_time('07', '21').index, 'time of day'] = 'Day'
```
Thank you so much again!

Comment: I'll answer these in the opposite order, as one is related to the other.

2. It appears you do not have a `pd.DatetimeIndex()`. `ts.between_time()` requires this. The code I have outlined will keep this intact.
1. The added date is an effect of setting a `pd.DatetimeIndex()`. We can format the date out. I'll edit the post for this.

Answer (score 0):

### An Alternative

If you want to use your own logic to process the data without using any datetime specific function, here's how you could do it.

> **Assumption**: Your `Time` column should have all entries as `str`. If not, convert that column into string with `df['Time'].astype(str)` and then pass it to the function `prepare_data(df = df['Time'].astype(str))`.

```py
import pandas as pd

def prepare_data(df: pd.DataFrame,
                 time_column: str = 'Time',
                 day_time_start: int = 7,
                 day_time_end: int = 23,
                 prune: bool = True):
    """Returns processed data (as a dataframe) for a given time-column."""

    _df2 = (df[time_column]
                .str.split(':', expand=True)
                .rename(columns={0: 'HH', 1: 'MM'})
                .astype(int))
    dfx = pd.concat([df[time_column], _df2], axis=1)
    dfx['Hour'] = dfx.HH + dfx.MM.between(30, 59)
    dfx['Hour'] = dfx.Hour + (dfx.Hour // 24) * (-24)
    dfx['AdjustedTime'] = dfx.Hour.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(2)) + ':00'
    dfx['DayOrNight'] = (dfx.Hour
                         .between(day_time_start, day_time_end)
                         .apply(lambda x: 'Day' if x else 'Night'))
    if prune:
        return dfx.loc[:, [time_column, 'AdjustedTime', 'DayOrNight']]
    return dfx

dfx = prepare_data(df, time_column='Time')
dfx
```

[image]

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        '19:05',
        '20:18',
        '20:44',
        '20:51',
        '06:11',
        '06:23',
        '08:37',
        '11:59',
        '02:22',
        '23:58',
        '23:18',
        '03:35',
    ],
    columns=['Time'],
)
```

Comment: @DianaMele Here's another option for you.